# The mechanism of runnable Go examples in pkg.go.dev

Tags: go, testing, godoc

There have two examples:

1. [fun Marshal](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/v5#Marshal):
   You can see the example are not contain any button.

   [source](https://github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/blob/v5.3.5/example_test.go#L10-L27)

   ```golang
   func ExampleMarshal() {
       type Item struct {
           Foo string
       }

       b, err := msgpack.Marshal(&Item{Foo: "bar"})
       if err != nil {
           panic(err)
       }

       var item Item
       err = msgpack.Unmarshal(b, &item)
       if err != nil {
           panic(err)
       }
       fmt.Println(item.Foo)
       // Output: bar
   }
   ```
2. [func Reverse](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Reverse) well it has three buttons: Share, Format, Run

   [source](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/sort/example_test.go;l=63-68)

   ```golang
   func ExampleReverse() {
       s := []int{5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 4} // unsorted
       sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(s)))
       fmt.Println(s)
       // Output: [6 5 4 3 2 1]
   }
   ```

[image]

I don't understand why one has buttons, and the other doesn't? Does the content (godoc) rendered have anything to do with the version of Go used in the repository?

Comment: Those with the `Run` button are runnable, i.e. they have a `main`, and they are in `main` package.

Comment: But the [source](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/sort/example_test.go;l=63-68) does not have the `main` it seems that GoDoc automatically generates `main` based on some mechanism.

Comment: There is a `-play` flag to enable the playground in `godoc` command, but I suspect pkg.go.dev is built with additional steps and/or imports additional javascript to make examples runnable.

Comment: I thought at first that maybe it was limited to go source code, and not third parties. But there is runnable examples in https://github.com/pkg/errors as well.
msgpack has its test in an `example_test.go` file with a `package msgpack_test` package and the correct function naming.
Maybe it's a bug?